# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected while executing Test class in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, logback

Exception while running Test class in spring boot Application:

```
2020-07-12 00:17:51,654 [main] INFO org.jsmart.zerocode.core.utils.RunnerUtils - ### testClass : class GetTest.GetFileTest
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'file:/C:/Users/Desktop/pts-mi-sourcecode/acquiring-api/common-config/target/classes/log4j2-local.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@20:13 - no applicable action for [Appenders], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@21:73 - no applicable action for [Console], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@22:19 - no applicable action for [PatternLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console][PatternLayout]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@23:14 - no applicable action for [pattern], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][Console][PatternLayout][pattern]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@27:200 - no applicable action for [RollingFile], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@30:26 - no applicable action for [JsonLayout], current ElementPath  is [[Configuration][Appenders][RollingFile][JsonLayout]]
```

Test Class:

```
import org.jsmart.zerocode.core.domain.JsonTestCase;
import org.jsmart.zerocode.core.domain.TargetEnv;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import testrunner.ZerocodeSpringBootRunner;

@TargetEnv("application.properties")
@RunWith(ZerocodeSpringBootRunner.class)
public class GetFileTest {
    
     

    @Test
    @JsonTestCase("test_Merchant_Profile.json")
    public void testGETOk(){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have configured your application to use the Logback libraries but are attempting to use a Log4j 2 configuration. Logback won't understand the syntax of a Log4j 2 configuration file. You either need to provide a Logback configuration file or replace the Logback dependencies with Log4j 2 dependencies.